# popen() or shell_exec() not work with at job control

Tags: php, bash, ubuntu, lamp

I am trying to design a website to let client choose the time at which our server should send a mail to them.

But this troubles me.

The following is send_mail.php

```
<?php $command = "mail -s 'title' abby8050@gmail.com";
      $handle = popen("at 20:42 07242016", "w");
      fwrite($handle, $command);
      fclose($handle);
?>
```

It will successfully send the mail at specific time on php cli, but will not work on website when the client clicks the link.

The following is part of website.

```
<div><a href='send_mail.php'>Send</a></div>
```

I've already chmod 777 send_mail.php.

I can not figure out why at command does not work through client clicking, but popen() works with other bash command through client clicking.
Is there some linux privilege issues I neglected?

Comment: I'm not sure if chmod 777 really helps. Some webserver configuration constellation do no like that. I'd rather set the correct owner of the files, with for example ```chown -R www-data:www-data <path>``` or similar.

Comment: Yes. I tried deleting www-data in /etc/at.deny. Then it works.